# php search date with different format

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

At my current database i use date format *yyyy-mm-dd*.
If i want to search by DOB then must use format yyyy-mm-dd to match it with default date format.

Is there a way to search DOB from whatever user input wether its dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd and give out the result???

```
$keyword = clean($keyword,1);

$result = $db->query("SELECT name, dob, email FROM user WHERE name LIKE '$keyword%' OR dob LIKE '$keyword%' OR email LIKE '$keyword%'");

if($result){
   //echoing the result
}
```

Comment: turn the column into a DATE column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily. First convert the user input to the correct format before passing it to the SQL query.

For example:

```
if (preg_match('~([0-9]{2})[-/]([0-9]{2})[-/]([0-9]{4})~', $input, $matches)) {
    return $matches[3].'-'.$matches[2].'-'.$matches[1];
} else {
    return $input;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could match UNIX Timestamps eg:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date)
SELECT * WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dob) = '$timestamp'
```

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php for more info on `strtotime()`

This will make it easier for checking within a date range.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should normalise the result in PHP before passing it to your SQL query.

Your code may look something like this...

```
$dateForSqlQuery = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input));
```

...assuming that `strtotime()` will correctly handle those variations.

On the other hand, you should really break up the user input into a separate day, month and year input, then generate the string yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime) to parse pretty much any (reasonably formatted) date to a timestamp, and from there you can convert to any other format.

For example:

```
$yyyy_mm_dd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('02/01/2012'));
```

It's quite a processor heavy function though, `strtotime`, so do be sparing!

Comment: If the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed.